# Setting default value for fields in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

So I have this model `Request`, that was working perfectly. I decided to add it a "status" field, with a default value

```
def change
    create_table :requests do |t|

        t.references :owner,     index: true
        t.references :pretender, index: true
        t.belongs_to :book,      index: true

        t.string :status, value: "pending", null: false

        t.timestamps null: false
    end
end
```

But now I get an COnSTRAINT NOT NULL on this line:

```
...
user.requests.build owner_id: oid, pretender_id: pid, book_id: bid
...
```

Which was working just fine. If the field has a default value, I shouldn't need to define it on the `build`method, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the migration file, the syntax is not `value`, it is `default`:

```
t.string :status, null: false, default: 'pending',
```

Comment: Wow, that is embarassing... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As MurifoX already has answered use the `default` option instead of `value`.

ActiveRecord has a really nice trick up its sleeve called [enumerables](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html). Basically you store the status as an integer:

```
t.integer :status, null: false, default: 0, index: true
```

And then in your model you add the values that the column maps to:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [:pending, :reserved, :foo, :bar]
end
```

This automatically gives you:

```
Request.reserved # scopes
request.pending? # interrogation methods
request.reserved! # bang methods to change the status.
```

Its also much faster to perform queries on the database based on the status since you are comparing integers instead of strings.

Comment: Now this is BADASS! I get the interrogation method and the bang method, but what does the first one do?

Comment: Oh, I see. You use the class name, not the instance! Cool! :D

Comment: The first one does `Request.where(status: :reserved)`